# Ray Tune Hyperparamter Optimization with XGBoost - TuneNoNextExecutorEventError| RayActorError

Tags: python, xgboost, hyperparameters, ray, ray-tune

I simply would like to tune my XGBoost with Ray Tune locally. However, my "actor" always dies unexpectedly before the ray trail could even start.

I tried different code variants and also checked memory consumption/availability (I have 48 CPUs and 256 GB RAM, so there should be no memory bottleneck).

Find below the relevant code snippets. Maybe someone could help and spot a mistake or give a hint what else I could try?

```
def train_xgb(config, data):
    clf = xgb.XGBClassifier(**config)

    clf.fit(data[0],data[1])

    predictions = clf.predict(data[2])

    prec = precision_score(data[3], predictions)
    
    tune.report(precision=prec)
    
    return {"precision": prec}

config = {
         "objective": "multi:softmax",
         "eval_metric": ["logloss", "error"],
         "n_estimators": tune.choice([5, 10, 15]),
         "max_depth": 5,               
         "learning_rate":0.01,
         "num_class":2,
         "booster":'gbtree',
         "gamma":0,
         "base_score":0.5,
         "random_state":42,
         "verbosity":1,
         "n_jobs":1
      }

trainable = tune.with_parameters(train_xgb, config=config, data=(X_train,y_train,X_valid,y_valid))

try:
    ray.init(include_dashboard=False) # Tried with and without this line of code
    analysis = tune.run(
        trainable,
        resources_per_trial={"cpu": 4},
        config=config,
        chdir_to_trial_dir=False,
        num_samples=3)
except Exception as e:
    print("An error occurred:", e)
```

Error Message:

> 2023-08-29 08:03:34,335   INFO worker.py:1544 -- Started a local Ray
> instance. View the dashboard at 127.0.0.1:8265
> 2023-08-29 08:03:35,193   ERROR trial_runner.py:1062 -- Trial
> train_xgb_8d72c_00000: Error processing event.
> ray.tune.error._TuneNoNextExecutorEventError: Traceback (most recent
> call last):   File
> "/home/.../miniconda3/envs/xgb-impl/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ray/tune/execution/ray_trial_executor.py",
> line 1276, in get_next_executor_event
> future_result = ray.get(ready_future)   File "/home/.../miniconda3/envs/xgb-impl/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ray/_private/client_mode_hook.py",
> line 105, in wrapper
> return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/.../miniconda3/envs/xgb-impl/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ray/_private/worker.py",
> line 2382, in get
> raise value ray.exceptions.RayActorError: The actor died unexpectedly before finishing this task.     class_name:
> wrap_function..ImplicitFunc   actor_id:
> 53ebd3abb1a0bfb346c3d56c01000000  namespace:
> 89f3dadd-4b17-422e-b640-19e35b2b81f2 The actor is dead because its
> owner has died. Owner Id:
> 01000000ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff Owner Ip
> address: 134.95.55.205 Owner worker exit type: SYSTEM_ERROR Worker
> exit detail: Owner's node has crashed. The actor never ran - it was
> cancelled before it started running.
>
> (raylet) [2023-08-29 08:03:35,179 E 3121452 3121496] (raylet)
> agent_manager.cc:135: The raylet exited immediately because the Ray
> agent failed. The raylet fate shares with the agent. This can happen
> because the Ray agent was unexpectedly killed or failed. Agent can
> fail when

> (raylet) - The version of `grpcio` doesn't follow Ray's
> requirement. Agent can segfault with the incorrect `grpcio` version.
> Check the grpcio version `pip freeze | grep grpcio`.

> (raylet) - The agent failed to start because of unexpected error or port conflict.
> Read the log `cat /tmp/ray/session_latest/dashboard_agent.log`. You
> can find the log file structure here
> https://docs.ray.io/en/master/ray-observability/ray-logging.html#logging-directory-structure.

> (raylet) - The agent is killed by the OS (e.g., out of memory).
> [2023-08-29 08:03:35,332 E 3115918 3121532] core_worker.cc:569:
> :info_message: Attempting to recover 2 lost objects by resubmitting
> their tasks. To disable object reconstruction, set
> @ray.remote(max_retries=0). 2023-08-29 08:03:51,198   WARNING
> tune.py:146 -- Stop signal received (e.g. via SIGINT/Ctrl+C), ending
> Ray Tune run. This will try to checkpoint the experiment state one
> last time. Press CTRL+C (or send SIGINT/SIGKILL/SIGTERM) to skip.